# TextArea Issues in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

Whenever I create a new TextArea, all the other textareas next to it seem to be shifted downward.

Can anyone show me the proper way to create two textareas side by side and have them each at a specific location? Right now, text area 2 goes below text area 1 even though i want them at the same level.

Code Now:

```
FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
VerticalPanel mainPanel = new VerticalPanel();
TextArea t1 = new TextArea();
TextArea t2 = new TextArea();
t1.setCharacterWidth(30);
t1.setVisibleLines(25);
t2.setCharacterWidth(30);
t2.setVisibleLines(25);
flexTable.setWidget(74,10,t1);
flexTable.setWidget(74,70,t2);
mainPanel.add(flexTable);
RootPanel.get().add(mainPanel);
```

Comment: What code do you have now?  Also important: what CSS and HTML are you generating along with that code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want both `TextArea` to show up in the same `FlexTable` cell you should wrap those two `TextArea` with a `HorizontalPanel`.

```
HorizontalPanel horizontalPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
...
TextArea t1 = new TextArea();
TextArea t2 = new TextArea();
...
horizontalPanel.add(t1);
horizontalPanel.add(t2);
flexTable.setWidget(74, 10, horizontalPanel);
RootPanel.get().add(mainPanel);
```